# Define your months during transforming String to Date

Tags: java, date, java-8

Is it possible to define your definition of months and then parse String into Date?

F.x.

```
String dateString = "9 Сентября 2004";
Date jud = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy").parse(string);
```

I would like to convert it to **Date**.
I believe I can define all my months first and then to transformation from String to Date.
I use Java8

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by _define all my months_?

Comment: @sotiriosDelimanolis: it means I will tell how my months is spelled. Let's say I have Russian or Polish naming of month, how would I parse? I believe it is possible to define naming of my month.

Comment: Yes, see below. Alternatively, you could just use the appropriate `Locale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to define the month names yourself. Use the appropriate `Locale` with the `SimpleDateFormat` object. For example:

```
Locale russian = new Locale("ru", "RU");

String dateString = "9 Сентября 2004";
Date jud = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", russian).parse(dateString);

System.out.println(jud);
```

Comment: btw, is it possible to tell for parser to ignore Up-Lower case for months? as far as I see SimpleDateFormat.parse expects lower case only.

Comment: I tried it out, case doesn't matter for parsing with `SimpleDateFormat`. If you think it's a problem you can call `toLowerCase()` on your string before parsing.